# WordPress How to redirect OR detect if Javascript is disabled, for Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, google-chrome

I would like my Wordpress site to have one of those redirects to a specific page if JavaScript is disabled on the site or display a message. Something that says something along the lines, "Please enable JavaScript to use this site.".

I am asking this, because all of the methods I've found do NOT work with Chrome because Chrome ignores the

```
<noscript> </noscript>
```

tag.

**This is what I have now, in case anyone is trying to find a method for this like I was.**

```
<div id="js-disabled"> 

// Shows when Javasript is disabled.

</div>

<div id="js-enabled">

// Shows when Javasript is enabled.

</div>

<style type="text/css">
    #js-enabled { display:none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('js-disabled').style.display="none";
     document.getElementById('js-enabled').style.display="inline";
</script>
```

Comment: I updated the question with the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like this

```
<div id="noscript">Java script is disabled ! </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('noscript').style.display="none";
</script>
```

Comment: It is not a half of the question because you ask about  Chrome issue and show js disable msg or otherwise redirect ("or display a message") and also improve code for match with your site is not my deal. I gave you exactly what you asked thankz

Comment: The non-thanking comment was an accident. The deleting thanking comment? I don't know why. In any case, I am still saying I have this method because of you. I just wanted to put my post showing the complete method I have now. I'll update the question with it. Thanks again!